# Get _id after Accounts.createUser

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to create a new user and use their _id for another collection right after it's created.

```
var newUserId = Accounts.createUser({username: "w/e", password:"w/e"});
```

doesn't work as I thought.

I know if you insert something into a collection it returns the _id, so I'd assume this would be same, but apparently it's not.

"newUserId" ends up being undefined.

I'm not sure if this matter, but I'm creating the user via server side.

Any helps is appreciated, thanks.

*Solved:

Got the code to do what it needed to do.

```
Accounts.validateNewUser(function (user){
//do something after user creation
});
```

slap that code into the account.js in the server side.

Once the user was created via

```
Accounts.createUser({})
```

the method:

```
Account.validateNewUser()
```

fire immediately afterward. Used the user argument to get whatever the new user properties I need (in this case the _id and username) and plugged that into another collection meteor method.

Thanks again!

PS: turns out

```
Accounts.createUser({})
```

Actually does return the _id, but you can only see it in the server console, but not the client console, so I apologize for any confusion. That was my mistake.

Comment: Are you sure this is running on the server? Is `username` unique? Is it showing an error in the console?

Answer (score 0):

To debug this, specify a callback then look at the error that is being returned.

```
Accounts.createUser({username: "w/e", password: "w/e", function(err){
  if ( err ) console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: `Account.createUser()` is asynchronous, therefore `newUserId` will be `undefined`

Comment: It's async on the client but will return a `userId` on the server [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser)